# Copy only necessary objects from PDF file

Tags: c++, pdf, podofo

I've got a huge PDF file with more than 100 pages and I want to separate them to single PDF files (containing only one page each). Problem is, that PoDoFo does not copy just the page, but the whole document because of the references (and so each of the 100 PDF files have same size as the 100-page PDF). A [relevant mailing list post](https://sourceforge.net/p/podofo/mailman/message/33216721/) can be found, unfortunately there is no solution provided.

In source code of function `InsertPages` there is explanation:

> This function works a bit different than one might expect. 
>   Rather than copying one page at a time - we copy the ENTIRE document
>   and then delete the pages we aren't interested in.
>
> We do this because
>   1) SIGNIFICANTLY simplifies the process
>   2) Guarantees that shared objects aren't copied multiple times
>   3) offers MUCH faster performance for the common cases
>
> HOWEVER: because PoDoFo doesn't currently do any sort of "object
>   garbage collection" during a Write() - we will end up with larger
>   documents, since the data from unused pages will also be in there.

I have tried few methods to copy only *relevant* objects, but each of them failed.

- Copy all pages and remove irrelevant ones
- Use XObject wrapping: `FillXObjectFromDocumentPage` and `FillXObjectFromExistingPage`
- Copy object by object
- Use `RenumberObjects` with `bDoGarbageCollection = true`

but none of them worked out. Does anybody have an idea or working solution for this problem?

Comment: It sounds as if you have reached the limitation of your open source PDF tool. Your only hope may be to file a feature request with them. My company sells the PDF [library](https://www.datalogics.com/products/pdf/pdflibrary/) which supports page insertion without the problem you are experiencing. Beyond that its API also supports PDF optimization which can squeeze further savings from your document (also available as a server tool).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dennis from the [podofo](/questions/tagged/podofo) support sent me an working example of optimized version of `InsertPages` function which is actually fixing page references and decreases document size significantly!

```
void PdfMemDocument::InsertPages2(const PdfMemDocument & rDoc, std::vector<int> pageNumbers)
{
    std::unordered_set<PdfObject*> totalSet;
    std::vector<pdf_objnum> oldObjNumPages;
    std::unordered_map<pdf_objnum, pdf_objnum> oldObjNumToNewObjNum;

    std::vector<PdfObject*> newPageObjects;

    // Collect all dependencies from all pages that are to be copied
    for (int i = 0; i < pageNumbers.size(); ++i) {
        PdfPage* page = rDoc.GetPage(pageNumbers[i]);
        if (page) {
            oldObjNumPages.push_back(page->GetObject()->Reference().ObjectNumber());
            std::unordered_set<PdfObject*> *set = page->GetPageDependencies();
            totalSet.insert(set->begin(), set->end());
            delete set;
        }
    }

    // Create a new page object for every copied page from the old document
    // Copy all objects the pages depend on to the new document
    for (auto it = totalSet.begin(); it != totalSet.end(); ++it) {
        unsigned int length = static_cast<unsigned int>(GetObjects().GetSize() + GetObjects().GetFreeObjects().size());
        PdfReference ref(static_cast<unsigned int>(length+1), 0);
        PdfObject* pObj = new PdfObject(ref, *(*it));
        pObj->SetOwner(&(GetObjects()));
        if ((*it)->HasStream()) {
            PdfStream *stream = (*it)->GetStream();
            pdf_long length;
            char* buf;
            stream->GetCopy(&buf, &length);
            PdfMemoryInputStream inputStream(buf, length);
            pObj->GetStream()->SetRawData(&inputStream, length);
            free(buf);

        }
        oldObjNumToNewObjNum.insert(std::pair<pdf_objnum, pdf_objnum>((*it)->Reference().ObjectNumber(), length+1));
        GetObjects().push_back(pObj);
        newPageObjects.push_back(pObj);
    }

    // In all copied objects, fix the object numbers so they are valid in the new document
    for (auto it = newPageObjects.begin(); it != newPageObjects.end(); ++it) {
        FixPageReferences(GetObjects(), *it, oldObjNumToNewObjNum);
    }

    // Insert the copied pages into the pages tree
    for (auto it = oldObjNumPages.begin(); it != oldObjNumPages.end(); ++it) {
        PdfObject* pageObject = GetObjects().GetObject(PdfReference(oldObjNumToNewObjNum[(*it)], 0));
        PdfPage *page = new PdfPage(pageObject, std::deque<PdfObject*>());
        GetPagesTree()->InsertPage(GetPageCount() - 1, page);
    }

}

std::unordered_set<PdfObject *>* PdfPage::GetPageDependencies() const
{
    std::unordered_set<PdfObject *> *set = new std::unordered_set<PdfObject *>();

    const PdfObject* pageObj = GetObject();
    if (pageObj) {
        PdfVecObjects* objects = pageObj->GetOwner();
        if (objects) {
            set->insert((PdfObject*)pageObj);
            objects->GetObjectDependencies2(pageObj, *set);
        }
    }

    return set;
}

// Optimized version of PdfVecObjects::GetObjectDependencies
void PdfVecObjects::GetObjectDependencies2(const PdfObject* pObj, std::unordered_set<PdfObject*> &refMap) const
{
    // Check objects referenced from this object
    if (pObj->IsReference())
    {
        PdfObject* referencedObject = GetObject(pObj->GetReference());
        if (referencedObject != NULL && refMap.count(referencedObject) < 1) {
            (refMap).insert((PdfObject *)referencedObject); // Insert referenced object
            GetObjectDependencies2((const PdfObject*)referencedObject, refMap);
        }
    }
    else {
        // Recursion
        if (pObj->IsArray())
        {
            PdfArray::const_iterator itArray = pObj->GetArray().begin();
            while (itArray != pObj->GetArray().end())
            {
                GetObjectDependencies2(&(*itArray), refMap);
                ++itArray;
            }
        }
        else if (pObj->IsDictionary())
        {
            TCIKeyMap itKeys = pObj->GetDictionary().GetKeys().begin();
            while (itKeys != pObj->GetDictionary().GetKeys().end())
            {
                if ((*itKeys).first != PdfName("Parent")) {
                    GetObjectDependencies2((*itKeys).second, refMap);
                }
                ++itKeys;
            }
        }
    }
}

void FixPageReferences(PdfVecObjects& objects, PdfObject* pObject, std::unordered_map<pdf_objnum, pdf_objnum>& oldNumToNewNum) {
    if( !pObject)
    {
        PODOFO_RAISE_ERROR( ePdfError_InvalidHandle );
    }
    if( pObject->IsDictionary() )
    {
        TKeyMap::iterator it = pObject->GetDictionary().GetKeys().begin();

        while( it != pObject->GetDictionary().GetKeys().end() )
        {
            if ((*it).first != PdfName("Parent")) {
                FixPageReferences(objects, (*it).second, oldNumToNewNum);
            }
            ++it;
        }
    }
    else if( pObject->IsArray() )
    {
        PdfArray::iterator it = pObject->GetArray().begin();

        while( it != pObject->GetArray().end() )
        {
            FixPageReferences(objects, &(*it), oldNumToNewNum),
            ++it;
        }
    }
    else if( pObject->IsReference() )
    {
        //PdfObject* referencedObj = objects.GetObject(pObject->GetReference());

        pdf_objnum oldnum = pObject->GetReference().ObjectNumber();
        pdf_objnum newnum = oldNumToNewNum[oldnum];

        if (!newnum) throw new std::exception("No new object number for old object number");

        *pObject = PdfReference(newnum, 0);

    }
}
```

Comment: Did you get this to work?  I have the same issue and have not been able to get this working completely.  There is no definition of FixPageReferences.

Comment: Also I've edited the answer and appended function `FixPageReferences()` implementation, which Dennis sent me after vacation.

Comment: Thanks @kocica!  With the definition of FixPageReferences() I was able to get this to work.  I modified the code a bit so it could be defined and compiled outside the library.

Comment: Glad it helped :)

Answer (score 3):

The only solution is to use another PDF library. Or wait for garbage collection to be implemented.

The problem is stated in the quote you mentioned:

```
> during a Write() - we will end up with larger documents, since the
> data from unused pages will also be in there.
```

This means podofo always puts the entire PDF content in your file, no matter what. The whole PDF is there, you just don't see parts of it.

Comment: Yeah, but also someone who has worked with this library could find out solution. I've tried it few times my self, but without any luck. Whole document has been copied or some pages were malformed (probably some references were missing) and PDF viewer could not display them properly (the problem occured at pages with some placed xobjects, like for example barcode). We cannot use different library and its quite big deal since we've got big PDFs and we need to process them fast.